# How to convert execuatble file format x86 processor to arm processor in QT SDK

Tags: linux, qt, assembly, cross-compiling

In my **systemA** im having **debian linux with x86 processor**.I installed **QT creator** on it that is working fine.

In my **systemB** im having **debian linux with arm processor**.I need to run QT creator executable which is generated in SystemA(x86 processor).

For that i installed G++ cross compiler.Then i added the installed cross compiler in QT creator manually in  *Tools->Option-->Build&Run-->Compilers-->Add*.Here I selected ABI as "**arm-linux-generic-elf-64bit**".

Now it in Kits it is showing the error like "The compiler G++ (arm-linux-generic-elf-64bit) cannot produce code for the QT version "QT 5.5.0 GCC 64 bit (x86-linux-generic-elf-64bit)""

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: maybe http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-crosscompiling.html will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is *cross compilling* your application.

This error means that you didn't ask to produce ARM code but x86 one.
Take a look at the [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-crosscompiling.html) @Zaiborg proposed.

You selected the right compiler but didn't set your project as ARM. Read that doc before asking more.

Good luck in cross compiling.

Comment: Actually ifound the error. While adding  compiler manually i selected QT Version option as "QT 5.5.0 GCC 64 bit "  that is for x86 processor.now i need to install QT version library file for arm processor. Do you know how to install QT version library file for arm processor

Comment: Yep that's what I said.
You will need to create your own cross compiling system like said onto the doc we give you. Read the doc and do the step by step commands in order to make it right. Good luck, it's a long stuff to do.